# Discord.js - 'Not a well formed URL' in embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, discord.js, malformed

In Node.js, I'm trying to send an image as the thumbnail in the top right of an embed. But if I just put the url as it is into the `embed.setThumbnail()` function, the image loads forever or cannot be loaded. The url would be this one:
`https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/./Oddworld:%20Abe%27s%20Oddysee-140x180.jpg`

I noticed that the special characters are making problems because urls without those work perfectly fine. So I tried to encode the url with

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
var boxart_url = 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/./Oddworld:%20Abe%27s%20Oddysee-140x180.jpg';

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
embed.setThumbnail(querystring.stringify(boxart_url));
```

But this still gives me the same error. The same goes when I try to encode the filename in the url only or when I try to use `querystring.escape(boxart_url)`. So do you know, how to encode the url? :)

**Edit**: As mentioned by Karizma, I tried to send the embed with just the url as the following:

```
const boxart_url = "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/./Oddworld:%20Abe%27s%20Oddysee-140x180.jpg";
const embeded = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
embeded.setThumbnail(boxart_url);
message.channel.send({embed: embeded});
```

The problem remains the same (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CirKd.jpg)

**Edit**: After some experimenting, I at least found, that the spaces are not the problem. It's the colon and apostrophy. I tried several stuff with this, like replacing the apostrophy with

`var boxart_url = "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/./" + encodeURIComponent("Oddworld: Abe's Oddysee-140x180.jpg").replace(/'/g, '%23');`
or different version of encodeURI() / encodeURIComponent() and I also tried to use a simple object as embed like

```
const embeded = {
    thumbnail: {
        url: boxart_url
    }
}
```

but nothing worked so far.

**Edit**: I came across my own solution. I cannot retrieve the image from the url with the embeds so I download the image locally before and then use this image as attachment for the embed. This seems to work :) i'll share the code here in case somebody else has the same problem.

```
const request = require('request'); //depricated !
const fs = require('fs');
const directory = "../data/images/boxart/";

var download = function(url, filename, callback){
    request.head(url, function(err, res, body){
        request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    });
};

download('https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/./Oddworld:%20Abe%27s%20Oddysee-70x99.jpg', directory + 'oddysee.jpg', function(){
    console.log('image downloaded');
});

let boxart_url = "data/images/boxart/oddysee.jpg"; // locally
const filename = boxart_url.substring( boxart_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 );

const file = new Discord.MessageAttachment(boxart_url);
const embeded = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
embeded.setThumbnail('attachment://'+filename);
message.channel.send({files: [file], embed: embeded});
```

Comment: Does it work if you replace the colon in the URL with `%3A`?

Comment: @LukeWoodward unfortunately not. `boxart_url` is recognized as a valid url, but it cannot find the image

Comment: npm querystring is meant for queries not url, for example: `?question="ben"`, I have tried the url itself and it works fine, the first time I tried though it never loaded though. https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2HVD.png, can you try it again with the just the url? If there's any errors add it to the post